# Cannot access public variable of another class

Tags: objective-c

I know this question is asked often, I've read so much on it but I still cant get it to work. Lets say I have two classes, FirstClass and SecondClass. FirstClass has a label and SecondClass wants to get the text of that label. Here is what I've done:

```
//FirstClass
@interface FirstClass : UIViewController
{
@public
    UILabel *theLabel;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *theLabel;

@implementation FirstClass
@synthesize theLabel;


//SecondClass
#import "MainGameDisplay.h"
@interface SecondClass : UIViewController
{
    MainGameDisplay *mainGame;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *theSecondLabel;

@implementation SecondClass

-(void) thisMethodIsCalled {
    mainGame = [[FirstClass alloc] init];

    self.theSecondLabel.text = mainGame.theLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",mainGame.theLabel.text); //Output is '(Null)'
}
```

theLabel.Text is not nil as it's being changed every second and is also displaying the label on the other controller which is running in the background whilst the SecondClass view is loaded. Could someone please point me to the write direction if I'm completely wrong, or show me some kind of example as to how this would be done. Thank you.

---

EDIT:

```
@Implementation FirstClass
@synthesize theLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self superview];
    [self startTickCount];
}

-(void) startTickCount {
            timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(timeChanger) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) timeChanger {
        theDay++;
        NSLog(@"%@",self.theLabel.text);
        if (theDay <= 9)
            self.theLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"0%i", theDay];
        else
            self.theLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", theDay];
        if (theDay > 27)
            [self monthChanger];
}
```

That's pretty much it. The NSLog outputs the day as expected.

Comment: Did you try setting self.theLabel.text in MainGameDisplay's alloc method?

Comment: That erased MainGameDisplays theLabel.text content. I'm really confused about what to do now.

Comment: OK. You're resetting the MainGame object every time your method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume MainGameDisplay is your FirstClass. Then in order to update theSecondLabel.text in you SecondClass object you need to pass an object of FirstClass and not to instantiate it in method call.

I guess you need to do something like this (this is a very simple example)

1. Add a property to your SecondClass
   @property (nonatomic, strong) FirstClass *firstClass;

After that:

1) create instance of FirstClass, let it have name firstClass.

2) create instance of SecondClass. SecondClass *secondClass = [[SecondClass alloc] init];

3) set property of Second class to instance of FirstClass

```
secondClass.firstClass = firstClass;
```

4) now you have a reference to actual object of FirstClass and can access its properties.

```
-(void) thisMethodIsCalled {

    self.theSecondLabel.text = self.firstClasss.theLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",mainGame.theLabel.text); 
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Yeah sorry that's the actual class in my program. I will post a bit more now.

Comment: The thing is that in you code you create new instance of FirstClass and if you haven't setup it in 'init' method you actually don't have 'theLabel', it is nil. Since it is legal to send messages to 'nil' in Objective-C and result of this operation will be 'nil' as well you will get 'nil' in self.theSecondLabel.text as a result. But anyway a bit more of actual code will help to answer correctly.

Comment: I added some more of my code, I don't think there is anything else that is relevant to add. I've never setup anything with an init method, is it the same as initWithNibName, and if so, what would I write in there?

Comment: Ok, I see. Now I assume that you want to get this updates in SecondClass in 'thisMethodIsCalled' method. Then you will have to pass you FirstClass object to an object of SecondClass. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, SecondClass has another timer that calls 'thisMethodIsCalled' every 5 seconds to keep the labels up to date.

Comment: Could you go on chat please? - iPhone / iPad.

Answer (score 1):

if you didnt leave out LOTS of code,

```
-(void) thisMethodIsCalled {
mainGame = [[MainGameDisplay alloc] init];

self.theSecondLabel.text = mainGame.theLabel.text;
NSLog(@"%@",mainGame.theLabel.text); //Output is '(Null)'
}
```

will not work.. nobody can modify mainGame in between the alloc init and the getting of .text variable....

[@all I know this is not an answer, but the formatting of comments sucks. Ill edit or delete it as needed]

Comment: Even if it is modified, wouldn't theSecondLabel.text equal theLabel.text that was alloc init'd?

Answer (score 0):

The method name is text, not Text. The case matters, and using text with a lower T will cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your code exactly, you have two problems. First, `Text` is unnecessarily capitalized. And, secondly, `TheLabel` is unnecessarily capitalized.

Edited Code:

```
-(void) thisMethodIsCalled {
    mainGame = [[MainGameDisplay alloc] init];

    // 'text' shouldn't be capitalized
    // 'theLabel' shouldn't be capitalized
    self.theSecondLabel.text = mainGame.theLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",mainGame.theLabel.text);
}
```

Comment: hd1 beat me to the answer as I was writing mine.

Comment: No sorry my bad, typo in question. This is not the problem. Will edit now. This would have given me an error and I would have noticed it anyway.